# Is there a conventional word that describes a professor for whom you were a TA

Tags: graduate-school, teaching, cv, supervision

I am providing a block of contact information to someone and the last line of this block it is requested that I provide the relationship between this person and myself.  Basically I am trying to find a concise way of saying:  `"Professor for who I was the (sole) course TA"`

Maybe this question is better suited to the English language forum, but because of it's academic, I figured someone experienced here might have an answer.  Here are some options I considered but found misleading and unusable:

- Supervising professor --> in academia this implies your thesis
- Professor --> Considered because it's a broad term, but again, in academia my first thoughts run back to the thesis supervision
- Supervising professor (TA) --> not sure it's obvious what the `(TA)` is referring to.

I don't think this will make much difference, but it's actually very important that answer to the above be as short as possible, as it is part of a short list of positions/interactions held with this professor.

Comment: TA supervisor??

Comment: @Kimball Thanks, this was actually one of the first things I had, but it was brought to my attention that in fields like chemistry/biochemistry lab groups for students frequently have dozens of TA's running and marking labs.  Sometimes everyone deals with a professor, or program coordinator, or in fact a senior TA who then deals with the professor.  I haven't decided whether this ambiguity is a deal breaker or not however, because ultimately it may not matter, and their other interactions with me may make their actual status as a professor obvious...

Comment: I am not a TA, but TA's on my campus often refer to this subject as the *assigned lecturer*.

Comment: @Kimball, If you wanted to add your suggestion as an answer, I would upvote it for sure, and it might be a better place for my earlier comment.

Comment: Well, I don't know that it's a standard term, or if there is one.  But, I think it's succinct and relatively clear, so feel free to use it!

Answer (score 2):

I would initially suggest terms *supervising lecturer* or *supervising teaching professor*. However, both terms are not perfect due to potential interpretation of "lecturer" and "teaching professor" as formal positions. In order to improve this, it might make sense to add clarifying term "class" and remove "teaching" from the second option. Therefore, my final suggestions are the following two options:

- *supervising class (course) lecturer*;
- *supervising class (course) professor*.

Comment: Ah, interesting approach, I am concerned that by leaving out my position, it will sound like I am a student, and this doesn't convey the relationship I wanted it to.

Comment: "Supervising instructor" avoids the issue that "lecturer" and "professor" are job titles.  (Admittedly, so is "instructor", but I still find it a much better generic term for the person-running-the-class than the other two works.  I am always a professor; sometimes I am the instructor for a particular class.)

Comment: @EngBIRD: In that case, just use "TA-supervising". It is not elegant, but, at least, it increases clarity. :-) Combine that with the nice advice from Jeff and you've got your solution: _TA-supervising instructor_.

Comment: @JeffE: I agree with your points. Please see my updated suggestion in the comment above, based on both the OP's concern and your advice (I hope I understood it correctly).